# Ruby While Loop Print

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get the numbers in `numbers` to print out.
But when the `if-expression` comes before the numbers are appended, it doesn't seem to print. Only if I put the `if-expression` after, it will. Why is this?

```
numbers = []

while numbers.size < 5
  if numbers.size == 5
    puts numbers
    break
  end
  numbers << rand(0..99)
end
```

Comment: Another way is: `Array.new(4) { |n| rand(0..99) } #=> [38, 92, 54, 57]`

Comment: Also as a side note, indent your code with 2 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have `numbers.size < 5`.
As soon as `numbers.size` is `5`, the `while` is no longer true. You can use `<=` *(or `numbers.size < 6`)* if you want it to ONLY print when it is exactly 5.

```
    numbers = []

    while numbers.size <= 5
        if numbers.size == 5
          puts numbers
          break
        end
        numbers << rand(0..99)
    end
```

Or you could write this in a more ruby style:

```
    numbers = []
    5.times do numbers << rand(0..99) end
    puts numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

1.**Case 1: If statement placed before appending**

The reason is because the loop will not execute when numbers.size == 5 because **the condition you've set is while numbers.size < 5.**

**2. If statement is placed after appending**

Placing the if statement after appending the numbers list will work because you're still within the body of the loop i.e. **you're still executing the loop for which the condition you set was true.**

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because the while loop exits before the if condition is true.

What's more, the `if` block is unnecessary and makes your code confusing and inefficient.

Lemme refactor it for ya...

**Generates an array of 5 random integers between 0 and 99 and then prints it**

```
numbers = []

while numbers.size < 5
    numbers << rand(0..99)
end

puts numbers
```